The node ID for newly created nodes is fetched but the node is not loaded
I have a custom module that loads all my nodes from type demarche_en_ligne, it worked fine for a few years but now when we create a new node it won't load.
For instance I created a new node and duplicated another (duplicated a node that loads correctly), the entityQuery returns 9 nids but \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids) returns only 7 results, the 2 nodes I added aren't loaded at all, I added a screenshot of the dump() below
Everything seems to work fine on the admin part, we can edit and save without problems, no error or notice is shown.
What I tried so far :

Flushing the cache
Checked the author and status (all created by the same author, all
published)
Tried to run the query with ->accessCheck(FALSE) and
->accessCheck(TRUE)

This is the code I am using.
$nids = array_keys(\Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'demarche_en_ligne')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->execute());
dump($nids);

$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')
  ->loadMultiple($nids);
dump($nodes);



Why are you using array_keys? You don't need that and just pass $nids directly to loadMultiple

@unusedspoon , I inherited this code from a coworker, I remove the array_keys and it worked ! Thank you

Removing array_keys solved the problem
